# Can eclipselink be used instead of hibernate in play framework 1.2.x?

Tags: jpa, playframework, eclipselink

Is there a way to configure / change the default jpa provider hibernate to some other like eclipselink in the play framework, or is hibernate "hard coded" into the play framework? More specifically I'm interested in the "[extending jpa pojo](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/extending-your-jpa-pojos.html)" - feature of eclipselink, something that is not as easily achievable in hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in theory Play only use JPA, but in practice they patch hibernate so that it work like the Play-team think is a better idea. I follow the mailing group over 1 year and doesn't see a successful switch of JPA provider. So I think it's not easy.
So what are possible solutions:

1. Your branch the source-code from play and adjust the code so that it run with eclipselink. The code isn't always well documented, but I found mostly easy to understand. So I think it's possible to do.
2. The second possibility is to switch to play2.0 which should get an RC in the next weeks. There it should be easier to use you favorite persistence framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this competent answer. I will try to achieve the feature with hibernate first.